# Angularjs uploading multiple files

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, servicenow

Our team is developing in ServiceNow and need the ability to upload documents and attach it to a case record.  After looking through several examples, we have a working example.  Our HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
```

In our controller, we have the following:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
```

We also created a dependency called fileUpload:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
            .success(function(){
        })
            .error(function(){
        });
    };
}]);
```

Finally, we have an angular provider called fileModel:

```
function fileModel($parse) {
    return { 
        restrict: 'A', 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel); 
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function(){ 
                scope.$apply(function(){
                  modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                }); 
            }); 
        } 
    }; 
}
```

Is there a way to modify this so that we can upload multiple files instead of just one?  We've added "multiple" in the HTML, but only 1 file shows up in our console.  I think we're missing something pretty obvious, but can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and check the console.

```
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="file" multiple="true" id="fileUpload" file="file"/>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</body>

//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
     $scope.uploadFile = function () {

        var fd = new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.file, function (value, key) {
            fd.append(key, value);
        });

         for (var pair of fd.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
        }
        console.log("hi")
    };
}]);

app.directive('file', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            file: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            el.bind('change', function (event) {
                var file = event.target.files;
                scope.file = file ? file : undefined;
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Codepen - https://jsfiddle.net/PratikPatel227/0rehq8g4/1/ (other)

Answer (score 0):

Did You Added
`multiple="true"`

In your Html?